# Hibernate Envers - org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate Envar for Audit purpose.

Here is my code and configuration

hibernate.cfg.xml file configuration

```
<!-- Audit -->
        <listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-insert"/>
        <listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-update"/>
        <listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-delete"/>
        <listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="pre-collection-update"/>
        <listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="pre-collection-remove"/>
        <listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-collection-recreate"/>
```

One Sample Entity Annoted with @Audited

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@Audited
public class User extends GenericDomain implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(length=100)
    private String name;
    @Column(length=60)
    private String username;
    @Column(length=130)
    private String password;
    // Getter and setter with more fields
}
```

I have created a RevistionEntity to log audit for logged in user, for whom we are logging audit as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REVISIONS")
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class CustomRevisionEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;
    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long audit_timestamp;
    private String username;
    private Long userid;
    // Getter and Setter
}
```

Here is my listener class

```
public class CustomRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        CustomRevisionEntity revision = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        revision.setUsername("username"); //for testing
    }
}
```

For Insert/Delete it works fine.

But for Update query it is giving following exception as

```
[ERROR] [http-8080-1 06:05:26] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:logExceptions:101) Duplicate entry '1085-3' for key 1
[ERROR] [http-8080-1 06:05:26] (AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:performExecutions:324) Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
        at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.beforeCompletion(AuditProcess.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.notifyLocalSynchsBeforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCTransaction.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:140)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy106.deleteSaleRecord(Unknown Source)
        at org.commission.controller.salerecord.SaleRecordController.delete(SaleRecordController.java:753)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.commission.util.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1085-3' for key 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2018)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
        ... 46 more
```

Here is my generic update code for all entities

```
public E update(E entity) {
        getSession().update(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: @Teinacher, Please check I have posted update code. This is happening only in case of Audit. Without Audit my CRUD functionality is working perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately without the full stacktrace and the SQL definition of the tables, its hard to say whats happening here. These are the things I would check:

1. Constraints/PK on the audit tables? - is it possible your primary key is missing the revision number AND revision type - I had this occur because an update and a delete happened in the same session for a particular entity (I think it had something to do with a Cascade operation, but I cannot recall now), and I was expecting the revision number + PK of the entity table to be enough to uniquely identify each row in the audit tables.
2. Remember that by default deleted entities only contain the revision number, revision type, and the ID/PK of the original entity. If you have a NOT NULL constraint on the audit table, that could cause the failure. You can work around that by setting the `org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete` property to `true`.

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue as your #1 there. My audit table is a many to many table with a `@JoinTable`and two PK columns, making it a total of 4 in the audit table. However I still get errors from hibernate after upgrading to all four columns in the PK. `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`. Your #2 is also `true` for me. Any idea why hibernate thinks it has the same identity?

Comment: Its a long time ago now, maybe post a new question with the definitions of your tables. I think in the end I just dropped the keys from the audit tables as it was simply too painful to maintain otherwise.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the view code to avoid this happening, a lot of hassle.